# Brightness of light sources

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, terminology

I would like to know what determines the brightness of light. I'm confused, After hours of reading, I got these definitions mixed up I need to link them together:

- Light intensity
- Brightness of light
- Number of photons
- Energy of each photon
- Wavelength of each photon
- Power of light source

Then I knew that there are different types of cone cells that respond to different sensitivity, does that mean less sensitive cone cells need more photons to respond and a number of photons is lost? And how is that related to light brightness?

Comment: You have correctly observed that "brightness" has two components, a physical one that is a measure of the actual   physical photon flux and a physiological, which represents the human eye's response to that flux. The latter is usually characterized by a "standard eye sensitivity" which is derived from averages of many physiological measurements. A table with these sensitivities can be found here: http://www.giangrandi.ch/optics/eye/eye.shtml.

Answer (score 5):

**Intensity** is an objectively measurable attribute of light.  It is the rate at which energy is delivered to a surface.  Intensity is energy delivered per unit time per unit area.  The intensity of light is a measurement of photon irradiance, which is the number of photons delivered per square meter per second.  You can measure intensity with a photoelement, such as a solar cell or a photomultiplier, which converts light to electric current.  As the electric current varies strictly with the intensity of the light, an objective measurement is possible.  The more energetic the photon (the shorter its wavelength), the fewer will be the number of photons required for a given intensity.  See this link: http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/photon-flux.

**Brightness** is a "subjective" quality of light.  It depends on the perception of whoever is viewing the light.  It can't be objectively measured, but it can be scaled, so that the same viewer (or viewers with similar perceptions) can agree that certain light is more or less bright.  For instance a less bright surface may be deemed 50% of the brightness of a brighter surface.  In astronomy, for example, stars may be graded according to their apparent magnitude, which is their brightness in comparison to a very bright benchmark star.  Brightness may also be called luminous flux.  Here is a list of units in which various luminous standards of brightness are scaled: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_flux

**Photon** is a term used to describe the particle attribute of light.  A photon may be considered the smallest packet of energy into which light can be separated.

You could deliver greater **intensity** by emitting light of a shorter wavelength, or by increasing the surface area emitting the light (greater surface area means more electrons emitting more photons).

The **energy of each photon** is measured in joules, and depends on the wavelength of the light according to this formula: Q = h*c / lambda, where Q is energy in joules, h is Planck's constant, c is the speed of light in a vacuum, and lambda is the wavelength of the light in meters.  Photons are considered to be "massless particles", but since a photon has energy, it must have mass.  This conundrum is solved by saying that photons have relativistic mass when they are traveling, but possess zero rest mass because they are never at rest.  Here is a better explanation: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/photon_mass.html.

The **wavelength of a photon** determines its energy, and its energy determines its wavelength.    The shorter the wavelength, the shorter the cycle of the wave, the greater its frequency, and the more periods of the wavelength can be crammed into a unit time.  Short wavelengths are more energetic than long wavelengths.  As photons of light possess both particle and wave natures, a photon when traveling has velocity (c), momentum (relativistic mass * c), and wavelength, but when a photon is emitted or absorbed (at the beginning and the end of its journey), it is considered a particle.

The **power of a light source** can be measured in watts.  A watt is the rate of energy of one joule per second.

Comment: In radiative transfer brightness is defined as the specific intensity per solid angle. Metrics for light can be so confusing and numerous.

Comment: Your description of intensity seems to conflate photon number with photon energy.  Is this really the accepted definition?

Comment: @boyfarrell: I tried to keep "brightness" separate from "intensity", per accepted usage for visible light.  Radiant intensity and luminous intensity are both measured, respectively, as watts per steradian and lumens per steradian.  But, as you point out, brightness apparently also may have similar usage.  Thanks for pointing this out, as one needs to be clear that there are numerous metrics for light.

Comment: @JimGarrison: My understanding is that intensity can increase EITHER with photon number OR with photon energy.  They should not be conflated.  For the same light intensity, you need fewer photons if they are of greater energy.  See this link: http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/photon-flux.  I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: It seems to be a little more complex than that.  
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_intensity), 
_Luminous Intensity_ is relative to a model of human visual perception
and would have no values for wavelengths outside the visible spectrum.
Then there are _Radiant Intensity_ and _Spectral Intensity_ with
different definitions.  I think the terms you want to use are Photon
Flux and Photon Energy.