Do we perceive colors through energy or photon counts?
For example, assume a light color red such that its frequency is half that of another light blue.
If you were to have 1000 red photons incident on your eyes and 1000 blue photons, then the blue light would be carrying 2x energy compared to the red. Would you see equal red and blue because of photon count, or more blue because of the energy?
I understand that we have photo sensitive cells will selective sensitivities as a distribution of frequency, Im asking if this sensitivity is to the energy or to photon counts. These are correlated, but as in my example vary a lot with frequency - blue light can have the same energy with half as many photons

The chromatic brightness that we visually perceive is a function of the responsiveness of the cones to the different colours of light. This is non-linear and nowhere as easy as you think; for example, ultraviolet light can be extremely bright and destroy your eyes, but you cannot see any of it; the same is with infrared.

I think how bright the light is is a result of photons entering the eye per second. Then the cones are sensitive to certain frequencies.

This problem is highly studied and important to colour TV, and so there are already experimentally obtained, committee standardised conversion ratios. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr

The eye is sensitive to both frequency and count. Green cones are the colour that can absorb the most energy that is distinguishable/useful.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191678/123208 Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMS_color_space & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space
